# Redirect form after submission (Form Action)

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I created a form using google apps script editor and I'm trying to open a link to a specific URL once the form is submitted

.html

```html
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="http://example.com" target="_top" 
onsubmit="myFunction()">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page");
}
</script>
```

In this part

```
action="http://example.com"
```

I'm supposed to replace the example.com with the page URL where the form is (just to reload the whole page as the alert says) but the form action is not working for some reason. Any help ..

Below are the complete codes as in my dashboard:

Form.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
</style>

<div class="ss-form-container">
<div class="ss-top-of-page">
<div class="ss-form-heading">
<h1 class="ss-form-title" dir="ltr">Test</h1>
<div class="ss-form-desc ss-no-ignore-whitespace" dir="ltr">WELD DATE 
00</div>
<div class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" id="Required">* 
Required</div></div></div><br>

<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="http://example.com" 
target="_top" onsubmit="myFunction()">

<input name="TEXT" type="text" placeholder="text" required>

<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

<div class="ss-q-title">JOINT
<span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span></div>

<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML(); ?>  
<select name="JOINT" id="JOINT" aria-label="JOINT" aria-required="true" 
required="">
<option value=""></option>
<? innerHTML.forEach(function(option) { ?>
<option value="<?= option.value ?>"><?= option.text ?></option>
<? }); ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page");
}
</script>

<script>
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()


function doPost (e) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
lock.tryLock(10000)

 try {
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

 var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues() 
 [0]
 var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

 var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
 })

 sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

 return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow 
 }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
 }

 catch (e) {
 return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

finally {
lock.releaseLock()
}
}


function createInnerHTML() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("CHOICES");
var namesValues = names.getRange(2,2,names.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
var innerHTML = [];
for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
innerHTML.push({value:''+ namesValues[i][0], text:namesValues[i][0]});
};
return innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: The code works when I try it. What do  you mean by "the form action  is not working"? - please update the question with your response, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your interest Traktor53. Yes when I tried the sample code outside of google apps script, It worked but still for some reason when I publish a new version of my google app script, it does not work so I will post the entire codes for more information

Comment: If you just want to redirect to the same URL when the form is submitted, what is the purpose of the last script in your html? (`<script>const scriptURL = ... </script>`) If you remove this script and change the URL in `action` to the desired one, it should redirect successfully. Is there a reason you cannot do that?

Comment: Thank you for interest Lamblichus. I tried to remove the script but the sheet doesn't receive any submits anymore. any ideas ??

Comment: @MahmoudBayoumi I posted an answer, please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the following actions to happen when the form is submitted:

- A new row is appended in `Sheet1` of your spreadsheet.
- You get redirected to the form.

You can accomplish this by following these steps:

(1) Remove the following script from your `html`:

```
<script>
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
</script>
```

(2) Change this line in your `html`:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="http://example.com" target="_top" 
onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

To this one:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec" target="_top" onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

(3) Change this in your `Code.gs`:

```
 return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow 
 }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

To this:

```
return doGet();
```

So the `try` block in `doPost` would be like this:

```
try {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
    return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
  })

  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

  return doGet();
}
```

In this case, `doPost` returns `doGet`, so `Form.html` gets loaded after the previous form data is submitted to the spreadsheet.

## Update

In case you want to redirect to another URL, you can do the following.

- Add an `onsubmit` trigger that runs a function `handleFormSubmit` that receives the form as a parameter (`this`). To do that, change this:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="http://example.com" target="_top" onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

To this:

```
  <form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="http://example.com" 
  target="_top" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
```

- Next, the function `handleFormSubmit` calls a server-side function called `addData`, and passes the form to it as a parameter. So add this script in your HTML:

```
<script>
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.addData(formObject);
  }
</script>
```

Finally, `addData` (previously `doPost`) receives the form object as parameter:

```
function addData(data) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
lock.tryLock(10000)

 try {
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
   var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

   var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
   var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

   var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
     return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : data[header]
   })

   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
 }

 catch (e) {
 return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

finally {
lock.releaseLock()
}
}
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thank you for your interest Iamblichus. The code is working now but all I need is to redirect the form to another URL (not the form URL) and of course keep the form sending the results to the sheet

Comment: @MahmoudBayoumi I updated my answer based on your comment, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: The below code has worked with me:

I kept everything as i was and just modified the below script for redirection purposes:

`<script>
  const scriptURL = 'Script URL'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open(After submit URL)
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>`

Now it's posting and redirecting. What do you think?

Comment: @MahmoudBayoumi I cannot check this now. Anyway, if you found a solution that works for you please consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prevent default on the form and open a new window using JS method

window.open()

This will not work on StackOverflow because of safety reasons.

```js
document.getElementById('Form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    
    window.open("http://www.example.com", "_top")
})
```

```html
<form id = "Form">


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest Ahmed. The above code gives an error "document is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. form is being submitted to provided action.

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="http://example.com" target="_top" onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and js part:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page");
}
```

Check fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cm59koat/1/

Comment: Thank you for your interest Waseem. Yes when I tried the sample code outside of google apps script, It worked but still for some reason when I publish a new version of my google app script, it does not work so I will post the entire codes for more information

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone,
I tried the below code and worked for me,
Keep everything in the question as it is but change this part only:

```
<script> const scriptURL = 'Script URL'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
form.addEventListener('submit', e => { e.preventDefault()
window.open(After submit URL)
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
.then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
.catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message)) })
</script>
```

This will keep the form posting to the linked sheet as well as redirect your form to the added URL after submit

Comment: Hi, are you sure you didn't change anything else in your code? I tried your approach and data coming from the form was not appending to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I tried to copy/paste the same code in a new sheet, it did not work. I created another question about it and the problem was solved. Check please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272746/google-sheet-is-not-receiving-form-submits