# Google sheet is not receiving form submits

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I created the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aghZREjkKSNkpCfWJUw_AMs1ZEoTIZOhDca4UHvuVtU/edit?usp=sharing

and from the script editor I created the below form:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
        .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()


function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
</style>

<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()">
<input name="TEXT" type="text" placeholder="text" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page");
}
</script>

<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxdtFz3L5Zczor9v-CGvm1yLzTogasSF__22oadV80ZFMQFH18/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open("URL after form submit", "_top")
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The same code is working for me in another sheet but when I tried to repeat in this sheet for some reason the form is not submitting to the sheet. Any help? And please would you give instructions in the proper way to copy the same code to other sheets so when I create another sheet with different columns and pasting the same code to the script editor, what needs to be done to make the script works for the new sheet and so on. Thanks

Comment: In your goal, where spreadsheet do you want to put the values from the form using the scripts in the copied Spreadsheet to?

Comment: Dumb question, did you publish/deploy the script? Also, if you just want to save the values from the web-app back to the sheet, why not just use `script.google.run` to send the data back to GAS to add to the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

### There are thwo things you need to change:

1. When you copy your script to another spreadsheet and publish it as a WebApp - `scriptURL` is going to change - please update it with the new one.
2. `var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))` is only going to work if you set up the property `key` for the new script. AS as workaround, just replace this line by `var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` - this will make the script automatically find the spreadsheet it is bound to.

Comment: Thank you for your interest ziganotschka. I updated the criptURL to the new one and replaced the Property key with getActive but still not sending the data to the sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: I tested it on your spreadsheet and it worked for me. Did you publish the script after implementing the changes as a new project version? And did you open your form with the new URL? Also, before your publish, you need to run the script manually once (even if throws you an error) - in order initiate the authorization flow.

Comment: I tried the script in the link https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293 and it worked but I can't find away to link the code.gs with the form.html. Can you advise?

Comment: The script in the link you provided is missing `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
        .evaluate()` in the `doGet()` function (instead of  `handleResponse(e)`) - this is the link missing. On the contrary, it contains the function `setup()` which you need to run manually to set up `key`. The rest of the script is almost identical to yours. You script should work after implementing the changes suggested in my answer and deploying the Web App as subsequently deploying the Web App as a new version.

Comment: Yes now it's working and I tried with a new sheet and worked too. I removed this part from the html 
`<script>
  const scriptURL = 'Script URL'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open("URL after form submit", "_top")
    fetch ...
</script>`

and added the script URL here `<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="Script URL" method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()">`

The form is redirecting to the script URL after submit. Can I change to another URL after submit. Pls advise

Comment: You can redirect to any URL you specify as `scriptURL` but if you want the data to be written into a spreadsheet - the script to which you redirect needs to have a `doPost(e)` function that proceeds the data.

Comment: Would you please provide an example of how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Just copy paste your function `function doPost()` into a new script file bound to the spreadsheet of your choice (make sure to include the line `var sheetName = 'Sheet1'`), deploy the new script as a WebApp and use assign the URL of the new WebApp to `const scriptURL` of the first Web App

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka, I tried this js in the html and it did the job

`<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page");
  window.open("https://www.example.com", "_top");
}
</script>`

and your idea is also perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please consider upvoting this answer and/or marking it as accepted to increase visibility for other users with similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

Okay the solution is;

Keep the original script in the question as is with the below modifications:

Remove this part from the html:

```
<script> const scriptURL = 'Script URL' const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'] form.addEventListener('submit', e => { e.preventDefault() window.open("URL 
after form submit", "_top") fetch ... </script>
```

and add the script URL here:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="Script URL" method="POST" 
onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

and for redirection purpose;
replace this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page");
}
</script>
```

with

```
<script> function myFunction() { alert("The form was submitted. Please press okay to reload the page"); window.open("https://www.example.com", "_top"); } </script>
```

thanks to all friends for help ..